# Create a table from added data sorted by month

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem sorting data and getting an array with the right data. Here is the situation :

I get a table of data representing invoices (creation date and price) in this format :

```
invoices: [
  0: {
    amount: 200,
    created_at: 1590572830425
  },
  1: {
    amount: 799,
    created_at: 1590572847553
  }
  ...
]
```

I would like to loop on this table of invoices, and extract the total sum of the amount of invoices according to the month of the year (thanks to the fields `created_at` representing a timestamp.

At the end, I would like to obtain a table with 12 values maximum, representing the total amount of invoices classified by month

Expected result : `[300, 450, 799, 650, 288, 400, 643, 809, 1073, 499, 640, 600]`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, try to always give a real input and output combination - i.e. ones that match (input maps to expected output), so that we can run it and test our output against your expected output. Also, often known as a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```js
const invoices = [
  {
    amount: 200,
    created_at: 1590572830425
  },
  {
    amount: 799,
    created_at: 1590572847553
  }
]

const outputArr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

invoices.forEach(item => {  
  const myDate = new Date(item.created_at);
  console.log(myDate.toDateString())
  const month = parseInt(myDate.getMonth());  
  outputArr[month] += item.amount  
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

Output:

```js
[0,0,0,0,999,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: No need to parseInt an int

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I expected. I have taken note of the minimum reproducible example, I will take care to formulate my question better next time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

As you would not want amounts to get mingled up across different years, it would be better to have a result that lists the relevant years, and then for each year, have the 12 sums:

```js
function monthTotals(invoices) {
    let totals = {};
    for (let {created_at, amount} of invoices) {
        let date = new Date(created_at);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        (totals[year] = (totals[year] || Array(12).fill(0)))[date.getMonth()] += amount;
    }
    return totals;
}

let invoices = [{
    amount: 200,
    created_at: 1590572830425
},{
    amount: 799,
    created_at: 1590572847553
}];

console.log(monthTotals(invoices));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this. I first did a reduce but that was overkill

This solution will not work across years

```js
const invoices = [{
    amount: 200,
    created_at: 1590572830425
  },
  {
    amount: 799,
    created_at: 1590572847553
  }
];

const monthVal = new Array(12).fill(0);
invoices.forEach(item => {
  const month = new Date(item.created_at).getMonth();
  monthVal[month] += item.amount;
});

console.log(monthVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can sum up the entire process in `reduce` method.

```js
var invoices = [ {amount: 200,created_at: 1590572830425},{amount: 799,created_at:1590572847553}];

var result = invoices.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  month = new Date(elem.created_at).getMonth();
  acc[month] += elem.amount;
  return acc;
},Array.from({length:12}, ()=>0));

console.log(result);
```